# Why does my self join return double rows? And how would I query the error in this table correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I've turned this question into a two part question.

I'm trying to understand the logic of self joins but for some reason I get twice as many rows as I think I should be getting here and I don't know why.

I also need to revise my query to prevent the extra row from appearing in the result

The table has user input errors where the begin date of a new ID2 should be the day following the EndDate of the old ID2.

The table is :

```
ID | BeginDate  | EndDate   | ID2
1  | 2000-01-01 |           | TEN
1  | 2000-01-01 |2010-01-01 | ONEHUNDRED
2  | 2000-01-01 |2011-11-11 | TWENTY
2  | 2011-11-12 |           | TWOHUNDRED
3  | 2000-01-01 |           | THIRTY
```

I need to do a self join that would expose rows where the BeginDate should have been updated but hasn't been. So for above we would only see the rows for ID1.

I also have a query that should take the one correct ID2 for each ID. The table error will return two ID2's where ID = 1  when I only want the correct one; the query is below.

```
SELECT ID2 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE inDate BETWEEN BeginDate AND NVL(EndDate, SYSDATE);
```

I had tried something like this 
    SELECT ID2 
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE inDate BETWEEN BeginDate AND NVL(MAX(EndDate), SYSDATE);

but MAX obviously won't work in the where clause.

All my self joins to try and expose these errors such as the one below return a row for each side.

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM Table1 v INNER JOIN Table1 v2
ON v.ID = v2.ID
AND v.BeginDate = v2.BeginDate
AND v.ID2 != v2.ID2
```

I think I just miss the point of how a self join should work.

I don't think I can compare the end date where they are null as Oracle won't do a comparison with Nulls.

Does anyone have any insight as to what I would need to compare in Table1 in a self join to only show the rows from one side of a self join?

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to choose MAX(End_Date) and take the one that is not NUll for the table above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no unique key on `id` and `begin_date`, so you may want to `distinct` the outputs as

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.*
  FROM Table1 v INNER JOIN Table1 v2
    ON v.ID = v2.ID
   AND v.BeginDate = v2.BeginDate
   AND v.ID2 != v2.ID2;
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.*
  FROM Table1 v , Table1 v2
 WHERE v.ID = v2.ID
   AND v.BeginDate = v2.BeginDate
   AND v.ID2 != v2.ID2;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected number of rows, change `v.ID2 != v2.ID2` to `v.ID2 < v2.ID2`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response however the ID2 is actually a nvarchar2 datatype. I have changed the table above to reflect this.

Comment: @dee- Even so, the < comparator should work, and should insure that you get only one of each pair and not both.

Answer (score 0):

Self join of this kind will give you numrows*numrows records.
But you limiting it with further rules.
Compare to null will always return false, but it will work.

Should be in total numrows*numrows-numrows-nulls.